# Do children threads die after parent's thread death?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on a multi-threaded program and I'm not sure about this.

Comment: No, they don't. Where did you get the idea?

Comment: Threads do not have a parent/child relationship. All the threads in a process are peers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, but threads marked as [IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) will die when their hosting process is terminated, whereas if `IsBackground` is false, they will prevent the process from terminating until they are finished.

Answer (score 2):

A background thread will only be terminated when all foreground threads finish if its IsBackground property is set to true. I'm assuming we're talking .NET :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx