# Child Thread shouldn't destroy when main thread finishes

Tags: .net, multithreading, service, threadpool

In .Net the child thread destroys when the main thread ends. Is there any way in .Net to keep the child threads running when the main thread ends or Service is the only solution to achieve this?

Comment: this may help you. Hope it works for you!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033577/do-children-threads-die-after-parents-thread-death

Comment: @Umar i want my thread to run all the time, once it has been started by an external source whether the application is stopped.

Comment: in which application are you using threads? is it winforms applicaion? or web application?